# How to change ImageView dinamically in UiTableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create a screen like the android screen below in iOS
[image]

My problem, in iOS is the circles. In iOS, I use ImageView for the circles with two png files: red_circle and green_circle. I need to use red circle for positive values and green circle for negative values, but I don't know how to check this condition in code. Can anyone help me? I'm using Xamarin.iOS with MvvmCross.

This is my UIViewController:

```
public partial class MyProjectsView : MvxViewController<MyProjectsViewModel>
{
    public MyProjectsView() : base("MyProjectsView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public async override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
        {
            EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        }

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(TblProjects, MyProjectsItem.Key, MyProjectsItem.Key);
        TblProjects.Source = source;



        this.CreateBinding(source).To<MyProjectsViewModel>(viewModel => viewModel.Projetos).Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(LblSyncrhonizingData).For("Visibility").To<MyProjectsViewModel>(vm => vm.IsProgressBarVisible).WithConversion("Visibility").Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(Activity).For("Visibility").To<MyProjectsViewModel>(vm => vm.IsProgressBarVisible).WithConversion("Visibility").Apply();
        this.CreateBinding(LblDataSynchronized).For("Visibility").To<MyProjectsViewModel>(vm => vm.IsDataSynchronized).WithConversion("Visibility").Apply();

        var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        var carregamento = new CarregamentoIOS(bounds);
        View.Add(carregamento);

        ViewModel.Carregamento = carregamento;
        await ViewModel.PreencheLista();
    }


}
```

This is my UITableViewCell:

```
public partial class MyProjectsItem : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("MyProjectsItem");
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("MyProjectsItem", NSBundle.MainBundle);

    protected MyProjectsItem(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            this.CreateBinding(LblProjectName).To<Project>(project => project.Name).Apply();
            this.CreateBinding(LblPercentage).To<Project>(project => project.PercentCompleted).WithConversion("IntToPercentCompleted").Apply();
            this.CreateBinding(LblCostMoney).To<Project>(project => project.Cost.Variation).WithConversion("DoubleThousandToStringAbbreviation").Apply();
            this.CreateBinding(LblCostDays).To<Project>(project => project.Schedule.Variation).WithConversion("IntToDaysAbbreviation").Apply();
        });          
    }

    public static MyProjectsItem Create()
    {
        return (MyProjectsItem)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }      


}
```

Comment: Where does your `ImageView` for your circle get defined? Perhaps you could create a converter/s that take you `ImageView` control and bind a `UIImage` based on the positive/negative value from you `ViewModel`.

Comment: I defined the ImageView in XIB file. I have two ImageViews for the circles and a folder in my iOS project that contains two png files: red_circle and green_circle.

Comment: Do you have context for your `ImageView` from within your  MvxTableViewCell?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in iOS. What is context?

Comment: Perhaps context is the wrong word, do you have scope/ can you access it from with the `MyProjectsItem` like you do `LblProjectName`, `LblPercentage` etc?

Comment: The context of my ImageView are ImgViewCostMoney for the circle on the left and ImgViewCostDays for the circle on the right. By default, in the xib file, I set green circle png file as image of ImageView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest solution for this would be to make use of a converter to do the switching of the image color based on the value i.e. if positive = red png and negative/neutral(0) = green png.

```
public class CostColorConverter : MvxValueConverter<double, UIImage>
{
    protected override UIImage Convert(double value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value > 0)
            return UIImage.FromBundle("images/red_circle .png");

        return UIImage.FromBundle("images/green_circle.png");
    }
}
```

You will probably need to update the `FromBundle` address to match where your images are stored.
Then add binding to update the images based on the values from your ViewModel.
Something like:

```
this.CreateBinding(ImgViewCostMoney)
    .For(c => c.Image)
    .To<Project>(project => project.Cost.Variation)
    .WithConversion(new CostColorConverter())
    .Apply();
this.CreateBinding(ImgViewCostDays)
    .For(c => c.Image)
    .To<Project>(project => project.Schedule.Variation)
    .WithConversion(new CostColorConverter())
    .Apply();
```

Note, I personally prefer using the strongly typed converter name approach but you can also just use the converter name as a string like you have in your question.